# Подгрузка сообщений чата

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Как сделать подгрузку сообщений для чата?

я хочу, чтобы через определённое время подгружались сообщения, если они существуют и без повторения.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
setInterval(function() {

var start = 0;

var form = new FormData();
form.append('id', start);
form.append('function', 'update_message');

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", '../ajax/websocket.php', true);
xhr.send(form);

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    var int = eval(xhr.response);
    if (int == null) return; 

    if (int.msg) {int.msg.forEach(item => {
        document.querySelector('.messages').innerHTML += item;
    })}

    start = int.id

}
```

}, 4000);

Answer (score 0):

Если не хотите использовать websocket, а все делать на js+php, то алгоритм может быть следующим:

1. В js в setInterval вешаете функцию, которая будет опрашивать бэкенд на новые сообщения. В качестве параметра запроса передавайте id последнего полученного сообщения.
2. В php получаете этот id, и делаете запрос в базу сообщений, где id>полученного. Ну и формируете json, отправляете его на фронт.
3. На фронте получаете json, и добавляете все эти сообщения в html.

Comment: А как мне получить последнее id что бы передать в PHP

Comment: Я как бы всё сделал только иза того что не знаю как передать последнее id у меня все сообщения повторяються раз за разом

Comment: @Гриша Вы же получаете из БД сообщения, уверен, у каждого из них есть id. Когда разбираете пришедший json, к примеру, к каждому сообщению можете добавлять data атрибут, например data-messageId. И в функции, которая делает периодический опрос, находите поледний элемент чата (в jquery, если используете, это делается просто), ну и у этого элемента запрашиваете дата-атрибут, собственно его значение и отправляете.

Comment: Я это знаю просто у меня проблема я отправляю с JS на PHP и мне в ответ приходит данные с PHP только я не могу обновить переменную id

Comment: у меня получаеться ответ приходит в функцию `xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {}` и в этой функции стоит переменная для обновление счетчика но переменная работает только в этой функции а не переходит в глобальную переменная назывветься `start`